# Lightning iteration does not accept inputText values

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputfield, iteration

I have the below markup in my Lightning component.

```
<aura:attribute name="items" type="InventoryAdjustWrapper[]" description="Items" access="public" />
<!-- <aura:attribute name="items" type="List" description="Scanned Items" access="public" /> -->


<aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item" >
<ui:inputText class="slds-input" value="{!item.Trans.MyApp__Quantity__c}"  />
</aura:iteration>
```

It does not seem to be accepting values. v.items is a List of wrappers from below.

```
public with sharing class InventoryAdjustWrapper {

    @AuraEnabled
    public MyApp__Inventory__c Inv{get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public Tra__c Trans{get;set;}
}
```

Console.log(v.items[0]) returns:

> Object { Inv: Getter, Trans: Getter }

Any clue as to why?

Comment: Can you post your helper code?

Comment: What do you mean by "Not Accepting" are you getting an error, nothing displayed, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Eric when I enter a value into MyApp__Quantity__c  and press tab or click somewhere it's reset back to initial value. It doesn't have any event to do that. But if I use a different field name for Value, e.g.  value="{!item.Trans.MyApp__Quantity__c}"   >> value="{!item.Trans.Name}"  it works fine. I find it strange for this particular field. I checked if the field is a formula, but it's not. it's a numeric field. I tried with inputText too. but same issue.

Comment: Suggest you update your title and question to reflect what your question / issue actually is